# Htaccess doesn't let access to sub directories with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to create a htaccess for seo urls, I created my htaccess all urls works fine exclude subfolder with parameters, they redirects to sitefolder.

`sitefolder` is my root all files are in there.

Example : Url should look like this :

```
  http://localhost/sitefolder/subcat/39/web-hosting
  http://localhost/sitefolder/profile/1/username
```

in htaccess its like this :

```
 RewriteRule ^subcat/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ subcat.php?q=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ show_profile.php?q=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]
```

First parameter is id and second is slug, but both urls doesn't go to url.

Here is all my htacces codes :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contact-us contact-us.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^login login.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^register register.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^search search.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us about-us.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ detail.php?q=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^cats categories.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^subcat/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ subcat.php?q=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ show_profile.php?q=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]
```

And this is how I Get parameters in `subcat.php`, I don't redirect to index on error so I dont think its because of php :

```
if(!empty($_GET['slug']) AND !empty($_GET['q'])) {
    $slug = $_GET['slug'];
    $pid = is_numeric($_GET['q']);
    $userQuery = $handler->getPosts("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE catId = ?", [$pid])->fetchAll();
   if($userQuery) {
      foreach($userQuery as $user){
         $catid = intval($user['catId']);
         $cat_title = htmlspecialchars($user['catName']);
         $cat_seo_url = htmlspecialchars($user['cat_seo_url']);
         $cat_descriptions = htmlspecialchars($user['cat_desc']);
         $cat_keywords = htmlspecialchars($user['cat_keys']);
         $cat_created = htmlspecialchars($user['cat_created_at']);
         $cat_img = htmlspecialchars($user['cat_img']);
      }

   }else{
      echo "Something went wrong while execute query.";
      exit();
   }
}else{
   echo "Something went wrong with parameters";
   exit();
}
```

Comment: Is `subcat.php` getting called? Are you seeing an external redirect to `index.php`? Presumably this `.htaccess` file is located at `/sitefolder/.htaccess`? Do you have another `.htaccess` file in the parent directory?

Comment: @MrWhite yes `subcat.php` and `.htaccess` is in `/sitefolder/.htaccess` and yes its called, there isn't a folder call subcat or profile they are just in url to tell the server which page should be called. I can see there is a redirect to index page when I call url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `subcat.php` is being called (as you appear to have stated in comments) then it's not a problem with `.htaccess`. But there are no redirects to `index.php` (or redirects of any kind) in any of the code you posted.

However, there would seem to be a runtime error with this line:

```
$pid = is_numeric($_GET['q']);
```

`is_numeric()` simply tests whether the argument is numeric and returns a bool, it's not returning the numeric value of that variable, which is what you would seem to be expecting. Consequently, your SELECT is always going to fail (or return the first item), regardless of the value of `q`.

You perhaps need something like this instead to retrieve the actual value of the stated URL parameter:

```
$pid = is_numeric($_GET['q']) ? (int)$_GET['q'] : 0;
```

But you need to be validating that these URL parameters (ie. `$_GET` vars) are passed in the first place, otherwise, your script is going to emit E_NOTICE messages.

---

**UPDATE:**

There is a conflict with your `RewriteRule` directives:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ detail.php?q=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]
> RewriteRule ^cats categories.php [L,NC]
> RewriteRule ^subcat/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ subcat.php?q=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]
> RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ show_profile.php?q=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]
> ```

When you request `http://localhost/sitefolder/subcat/38/web-design` it's going to be caught by the first rule here which rewrites the request to `detail.php?q=subcat/39&slug=web-design`, not `subcat.php` as you are expecting. Which presumably *fails*, since `q=subcat/39` is probably invalid (and I would guess is triggering the redirect to `/sitefolder/`)?

You need to change the order of these rules and/or make the regex more specific to avoid a conflict. eg. If `q` should be a numeric id then match just a numeric value (`\d+`), instead of literally *anything* (`.*`), which is what you are currently matching.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^contact-us contact-us.php [L,NC]
> ```

You should also include end-of-string anchors on your regex, otherwise these rules will also match the rewritten URL and cause an unnecessary loop. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ contact-us.php [L,NC]
```

I would also question the use of the `NC` flag here, since it's potentially creating a duplicate content issue by allowing `contact-us` and `CONTACT-US` (and everything between) to access the same resource.

#### Summary

In other words, your rules should be more like this:

```
RewriteRule ^contact-us$ contact-us.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^register$ register.php [L]
RewriteRule ^search$ search.php [L]
RewriteRule ^about-us$ about-us.php [L]
RewriteRule ^cats$ categories.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([\w-]+)$ detail.php?q=$1&slug=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^subcat/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$ subcat.php?q=$1&slug=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^profile/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$ show_profile.php?q=$1&slug=$2 [L]
```

(`\w` is a shorthand character class for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.)

By making the regex more specific you avoid a conflict. The directives execute top to bottom. The first rule that matches wins.

Comment: I removed everything in subcat.php exclude php codes in question and tried your solution and 
   `if(!empty($_GET['q'])){
      $pid = $_GET['q']; 
   } else {
      echo $_GET['q'];
   }` but still redirects to **sitefolder**

Comment: To clarify, you see an external redirect in the browser devtools _after_ `subcat.php` is called? There are no redirects or references to `index.php` in the code you posted? Is it redirecting to `/sitefolder/` or `/sitefolder/index.php`?

Comment: Make sure you're not seeing a cached response. Test with the "Network" tab open in browser devtools and "Disable cache" checked. What 3xx redirect code are you seeing? What are the response headers of the redirect?

Comment: sorry my bad. its redirecting to `/sitefolder/` I just edited question.  when I click to this url in browser `http://localhost/sitefolder/subcat/38/web-design` it goes to `/sitefolder/`. when I click `sitefolder/subcat.php?q=38&slug=web-design` it works fine. no cached response I clear browser history each time. strange isn't it :(

Comment: @kaderkandar Actually you do have a conflict with the `RewriteRule` directives in `.htaccess`. That request would be rewritten to `detail.php`, not `subcat.php`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: isn't `RewriteRule ^subcat/` subcat is specific and making difference ? let me try to change q.

Comment: The order of the rules is important. The preceding (more generic) rule catches the request first. The more specific rules need to be first.

Comment: Finally I changed .htaccess to `RewriteRule ^subcat/([^/]+)/?$ subcat.php?es=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` and it worked. (**not sure if its correct**) Thanks for your advice, I will add anchors. I will ask another question about use of `NC`

Comment: @kaderkandar I've added a summary of what the rules should look like. Regarding the use of `NC` - do you need case-insensitive URLs? (Usually that is something to avoid.)

Comment: Ok you saved my life thanks, I been working on this since two days :( Thanks again. no really I dont need case-insensitive URLs