# How to redirect URL with query string without name to new url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have these URLs

```
https://example.com/team?1892
https://example.com/team/?1892
```

which I need to redirect to

```
https://example.com/team/whatever/
```

How can I do that? I only find redirect solutions where the query strings have names. Thanks for suppport!

Comment: Do you have a `RewriteRule` that makes `/team/whatever/` powered by the form with the query string?

Comment: No, these are old urls indexed in google from an old website that does no longer exist. We need to redirect those to new urls.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/72051172/12232340

Comment: Thanks! The solution of Stephen worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```sh
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^1892$
RewriteRule ^/?team/?$ /team/whatever/ [R=301,L,QSD]
```

In English: if the query string is exactly "1892" and the URL path is "/team/" (with optional slashes), then redirect it to "/team/whatever/" without preserving the query string, using a 301 permanent redirect.

Comment: One more thing: The rewrite leads to the http:// version. How can I make sure it loads https:// ?

Comment: It should use the current protocol.  Your site may be behind a proxy, CDN, or load balancer and apache doesn't know about the HTTPS.  You can fix it by using the full URL: `RewriteRule ^/?team/?$ https://example.com/team/whatever/ [R=301,L,QSD]`