# How can i redirect one url to another url using .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am stuck at redirecting one url to another url.

I want to redirect

```
https://samedomain.com/page-check-927GSJAYS639AL/highlights
```

to

```
https://samedomain.com/page-highlights/
```

(927GSJAYS639AL this is id it can be anything)

the `http://samedomain.com/page-highlights/` is the wordpress page

The rewrite rule I tied is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page-check-([A-Z0-9]*)/highlights /page-highlights/?id=$1 [L]
```

but i see 404 error page

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72051172/12232340

Comment: @anubhava: thank you for your response
i want to show ```https://samedomain.com/page-check-927GSJAYS639AL/highlights``` this URL but ```https://samedomain.com/page-highlights/
``` this WP page content

Comment: For WP URLs internal rewrite should be handled using WP rewrite API php code

Comment: @anubhava:  tried the following code, it didn't work
```add_action( 'init', 'ao_add_rewrite_rule');
function ao_add_rewrite_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule( '^page-check-([A-Z0-9]*)/highlights', '/page-highlights/?id=$1', 'top');
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}```

Comment: Sorry I am not a WP expert but `/page-highlights/?id=927GSJAYS639AL` probably doesn't work on your WP

Comment: @anubhava thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work. :(